# How scanf("%d", i) is working?

Tags: c, scanf

Consider this code snippet (Instead of using scanf(%d,&i) i am deliberately using scanf("%d", i))

```
int main()
{
 int i;
 scanf("%d", i);
 printf("%d", i);
 return 0;
}
```

Here i is not initialized and code is running with warning, scanning the input and giving garbage value as output.

But if i is initialized with some value then it scans the input and program crashes.

How exactly scanf() is working in both cases ?

Comment: Its not because it *appears* to work that it does. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Haphazardly. Invoking UB ruins the best day.

Comment: `scanf` is (probably) treating the garbage value of `i` as a pointer, and trying to store an `int` value at the specified location. If you're lucky, the program crashes (crashing is a way of telling you that there's a serious error). If you're unlucky, it doesn't. If it doesn't crash, `i` retains the garbage value it had before the call to `scanf`. When you initialize `i`, you're probably giving it a value that's more likely to be interpreted as an invalid address. Incidentally, the `#include <stdio.h>` is not optional.

Comment: @user3121023 I know the format of scanf and also that I have to give address of the variable. I am just trying this.

Comment: Argh. Three people want to close as no-repro or typo. It's neither for sure.

Comment: @ABJK: If you understand that this is undefined behavior, but you want to understand how a particular compiler might compile it, then perhaps you should say that in your question.

Comment: @sharth exactly! I have edited that I am deliberately using that argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you used the proper `#include <stdio.h>` and just did not mention it.

In that case, there is exactly one bad line:

```
 scanf("%d", i); // This line is bad
```

There are two ways you invoke [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984) here:

1. Reading `i`, even though it was never assigned invokes UB because it is of auto-storage-class (stack-allocated) and you never take its address (it qualifies for `register`).
2. Passing an `int` where `scanf` expects `int*` causes UB all by itself. The argument should be `&i`.
   Do you have any idea what you are potentially destroying there, if it "seems to work"?

You initializing `i` would remove the first but not the second cause of UB.

Aside: You should always assume that input may fail, so check the return-value.

BTW: If you check, compilers can and do take advantage of UB to prune the entire branch of execution which would result in it as "impossible, no need to worry about it".
That is one of the common tricks they use to shrink code-size and obtain optimal performance.

If you want to know what your compiler, the version you use today with the exact code and options you give it does, look at the disassembly or maybe ask for an assembly-listing. Though do not make any conclusions with regard to it being "harmless".

Comment: so crash in the second case and not in the first is just because of my compiler and I will get different outcome on different compiler ?

Comment: @ABJK: Might get different output, on different implementation or day or with different options or just because. No guarantee though.

Comment: Thanks for getting the exact question and for your answer.

Comment: @ABJK also, don't *ever* use `scanf()` in modern code. use `getc()` or `fgets()` bound into a parser such as `strtol()` for getting user input.

Answer (score 4):

So, you've invoked undefined behavior<sup>1</sup> in two ways:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", i);
```

First of all, the `%d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int *`.  The expression `i` has type `int`; since this doesn't match the expected type, the behavior is undefined.  This will definitely be a problem if `sizeof (int *) != sizeof (int)`, among other issues.

Secondly, since `i` is uninitialized, it will contain some *intederminate* value that `scanf` will interpret as a pointer value and try to write input to that invalid address (which is *not the address of `i`*).  In this particular case, writing to that invalid address doesn't immediately lead to a segfault (although it's clobbered *something*; whether that something is important is an open question).  Note that *`i` is not modified*; it still contains the same indeterminate value that it started with.

In the second case, whatever you initialized `i` to probably resolved to a restricted address, which is why you crashed.

Either way, bad juju.

---

<sup>1.  Where the definition of **undefined behavior** is "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which [the C language standard] imposes no requirements" ([2011 C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 3.4.3).  The compiler isn't required to issue a diagnostic or halt translation, nor is it required to generate code that does any specific thing.  Code may crash, it may corrupt data, it may leave the program in a bad state, or it may appear to work correctly.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You called scanf with invalid arguments. Instead of

```
scanf("%d", i);
```

there has to be

```
scanf("%d", &i);
```

The function writes the extracted number to the object addressed by &i.

Comment: OP says that he used `scanf` without `&` deliberately.

Comment: @Cool Guy As usual he edited his post.